# Why the compiler raises an error on my constructor call?

Tags: java, class

I am getting this error:

> Constructor Fraction in Fraction class cannot b applied to given types

I think the issue is with the last method `multiply`. I'm trying to return a new instance of object Fraction with the numerator field multiplied by the parameters.

```
public class Fraction {   
    private int numerator; 
    private int denominator;    
    public Fraction() {
        numerator = 0; 
        denominator = 1;
    }

    public void setNumerator(int newNum) {
        numerator = newNum;
    }

    public void setDenominator(int newDenom) {
        denominator = newDenom;
    }

    public int getNumerator() {
        return numerator;
    }

    public int getDenominator() {                           
        return denominator;
    }

    public double getValue() {
        return (double) numerator/denominator;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return numerator + "/" + denominator;
    }

    public Fraction multiply(int num) {
        return new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`new Fraction(numerator, denominator)` - You `Fraction`'s constructor doesn't take parameters; `public Fraction()`

If you want this functionality, you will need to implement it

```
public Fraction() 
{
    this(0, 1);
}

public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) 
{
    this.numerator = numerator; 
    this.denominator = denominator;
}
```

as an example

Comment: Did you intend for your example constructor to ignore its parameters?

Comment: @azurefrog Thank you, I copy and pasted the original constructor values down over my previous values and forget to update them (remembered to put `this.` in though :P)

Answer (score 4):

There is no matching constructor in your `Fraction` class that takes numerator and denominator as input and hence the error on this line:

```
return new Fraction(numerator, denominator);
```

Define a constructor to take arguments, may be like this:

```
public Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) 
{
    this.numerator = numerator; 
    this.denominator = denominator;
}
```

Comment: How can i make the constructor automatically set the value of numerator to 0 and denominator to 1 while still allowing it to take arguments? Is this possible? Also, thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Alex What is the purpose of calling an argument constructor if you don't want use the arguments. If you have a real reason for that then simply assign the default values instead of using the passed arguments.